# How to adjust the table height to the number of items in SWT with GridLayout?

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

I would like to have a table which height is exactly adjusted to the number of items. I'm working with SWT and I'm using a `GridLayout`. This is an excerpt of my code:

```java
Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);
TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
tc1.setText("Column1");
tc2.setText("Column2");
tc1.setWidth(85);
tc2.setWidth(90);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText(0, "Text Column1");
    item.setText(1, "Text Column2");
}

GridData gridData = new GridData(tc1.getWidth()+tc2.getWidth()-17, ???);
table.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

For the width I have found a formula. But for the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Table::getItemHeight()` to calculate the necessary client height for the given number for items. Then use `computeTrim()` to compute the bounds for the given client height. if grid lines are shown the width of each separating line is added. And finally, you can use the `heightHint` of `GridData` to advise the `GridLayout` to reserve a certain height for the table.

For example:

```java
int clientWidth = ...
int clientHeight = table.getItemHeight * numberOfItems;
if( table.getLinesVisible() && numberOfItems > 0 ) {
  clientHeight += table.getGridLineWidth() * ( numberOfItems - 1 );
}
Rectangle bounds = table.computeTrim( 0, 0, clientWidth, clientHeight );

GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.DEFAULT, clientHeight );
```

If your client width is computed elsewhere, you can as well set it to zero.

Comment: Thank you!  int clientHeight = (table.getItemHeight() * items.length)+7;   works for me

Comment: When using constant pixel offsets like '7', please keep in mind that these won't work across all platforms / screen resolutions / environment settings.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!